# AWS credentials work when in config file but not as env vars?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The command:

```
aws s3 ls
```

works fine when my credentials are stored in `~/.aws/credentials`.

When I run the following bash script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
env_vars=$(cat ~/.aws/credentials | tail -n +2 | sed -e 's/ *//g' | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' | tr '\n' ' ')
echo ${env_vars}


env ${env_vars} aws s3 ls
```

which just extracts the env vars out of a config file, I get the error:

```
An error occurred (SignatureDoesNotMatch) when calling the ListBuckets operation: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.
```

Given that the credentials are identical, what could be going wrong?
Adding `--region us-west-2` (my S3 region) doesn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the last two lines of your `~/.aws/credentials` file are values for `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`, and there's no extra environment variables causing trouble.

The problem is that your conversion script is mangling the secret key by uppercasing it.

`aws_access_key_id`  is fine because it is always an uppercase string anyway, but `aws_secret_access_key` contains upper and lower case characters, as well as digits and symbols.

Alter your bash script similar to:

```
env_vars=$(cat ~/.aws/credentials | tail -n +2 | sed -e 's/ *//g' | awk -F = '{print toupper($1) "=" $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')
```

Which only uppercases the portion of the configuration file lines before the `=`.